# Store init parameters of a class and its subclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-decorators

I have a class and I want to be able to store the name and value of arguments given when I create a new instance of the class or any subclass (subclasses init having more parameters than superclass).

```
def init_store(init):
    @wraps(init)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        self = args[0]
        fields = args[1:]
        field_dict = {arg_name: arg_val for arg_name, arg_val in zip(init.__code__.co_varnames[1:], fields)}
        self.init_values = dict(**field_dict, **kwargs)
        self.init_values['Problem'] = type(self).__name__
        init(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Currently i decorate the init of all my subclasses with this function, and this is doing the job.
But is there a way to have the same effect without having to decorate each init ?
Looking around I've seen somehow similar things being done with metaclasses but I've never used them and I couldn't find a way to apply them here.

Thanks by advance !

Comment: It seems like this would be much simpler if you designed your classes to only use keyword arguments; then you just need the subclasses to pass all their arguments to `super().__init__`, and your base class `__init__` can take care of simply saving `**kwargs` without any need to decorate any methods.

Comment: Yeah works great this way, but i prefer not having to change my classes to taking only kwargs

Comment: Why? `super` is much easier to use correctly if you don't have to consider the order in which arguments are passed to various methods.

Comment: I would prefer the class to be as easy to use as possible. For super I don't really get benefices as the main class only has one argument.
Maybe I'm missing something I'm beginning with heritages !
If you think this is the best way I'll do so.
Thank you !

Comment: The main class has only one, but each subclass might introduce conflicting positional arguments. Keyword arguments identify themselves and don't rely on the order in which they are passed.

Comment: I was changing my classes to only take kwargs but i still have an issue:
One class has a default value for an argument, so what would be the best way to handle it ?
Doing something like this ? if not kwargs['f']: self.f = default_value

Comment: @vjjhgj see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change to using only keyword args, you can capture the positionals too. More or less like this, you'll adapt for whatever way you like to store and access the args:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.called_with = dict(
            name = self.__class__,
            positionals = args,
            keywords = kwargs
            )
        print(args, kwargs)

class D(C):
    pass

c1 = C(1,2,3,a='A',b='B')
print(c1.called_with['name'])
print(c1.called_with['positionals'])
print(c1.called_with['keywords'])

print()

d1 = D(1,2,3,4,d='D')
print(d1.called_with['name'])
print(d1.called_with['positionals'])
print(d1.called_with['keywords'])
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, 3) {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'}
<class '__main__.C'>
(1, 2, 3)
{'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'}

(1, 2, 3, 4) {'d': 'D'}
<class '__main__.D'>
(1, 2, 3, 4)
{'d': 'D'}
```

And of course you can use `super().__init__(args, kwargs)` from the subclasses init when they need it.

However, as per the various comments here and with @chepner insights, it is obvious both that the OP wants to use keyword args (by requirement and because they are convenient) and that mixing positionals will only make the code messy, because with them classes need to know a lot about their hierarchical relations, to distinguish their positional args from the other classes args in their order). Classes will be highly coupled with that info, and that's wrong.

So just use keyword args.

As for default values, this will do:

```
if not 'somekey' in kwargs:
    kwargs['somekey'] = default_value
```

Comment: Using positional arguments gets messy if you start having subclasses that introduce their own positional arguments. Say `A` has one argument, `B` and `C` each inherit from `A` and add their own second argument, then `D` inherits from `B` and `C`. How do you interpret `D(1, 2, 3)`?

Comment: I don't really have this problem as the only parameter for super depends on the subclass i'm in, not on the parameters used when creatint instance for sublass
The sublcass init looks like:
```
def __init__(self, *args):
    # Use args
    super().__init__(True)
```

Comment: @chepner, You are right, and your comment "The main class has only one, but..." makes your point very clear. I was just not getting the OP intent in all this. I see your example quite simply. A D instance with those positionals. Do whatever you want with them. The same when passing them to super. Yes, this is silly. It implies that a class knows its place in the hierarchy to select the proper arg. And that's coupling the classes with too much knowledge about each other. I never needed to write code like this (but that just me), that's why I haven't thought much about it. I'm editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not work as I want to store the args names aswell
ex of current version effet:
Declaration:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class B(A):
    @init_store
    def __init__(self, a1, a2):
        self.a1, self.a2 = a1, a2
        super(B, self).__init__(True)
```

Calling:

```
b = B(1, 2)
print(b.init_values)
```

Output:

```
'{'a1': 1, 'a2': 2, 'Problem': 'B'}'
```

Comment: If you want to store the arg names, you are saying that you need to use keyword args in the instance creation calls.